Extract part of an Excel formula in another cell
I want to extract the numerical part of this formula, so I can work with it in another cell:
=8464184.94*$S35
The formula is in R35.
I did see the post in Is it possible to extract part of a formula in excel? but despite what is said there, there is no such function as EVALUATE() in standard Excel (in my Case Excel 2021 DESKTOP).
=RIGHT(LEFT(FORMULATEXT(R35),(FIND("*",FORMULATEXT(R35),1)-1)),LEN(LEFT(FORMULATEXT(R35),(FIND("*",FORMULATEXT(R35),1)-1)))-1)

works but is, as you can see, pretty ghastly.

Try: =TEXTAFTER(TEXTBEFORE(FORMULATEXT(R35),"*"),"=") don't think this needs the Evaluate() feature of Excel which uses Excel Macro 4.0 functions

Or with older versions: =LET(a, FORMULATEXT(R35),TRIM(LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(RIGHT(a,LEN(a)-1),"*",REPT(" ",100)),100)))

The first one returned a NAME error; second one worked. Not allowed to upvote your comment or answer, so thank you. I have to avoid macro functions, VBA and add-ins, otherwise these workbooks won't work for the the people I send them to.

Is it always a multiplication? then maybe the reverse operation will provide the desired result: =R35/$S35

@cybernetifc.nomad - Yes, it is "always" multiplication in this specific instance. To Mayukh Bhattacharya - TEXTSPLIT(), TEXTAFTER(), and TEXTBEFORE() are not in Exce; 2021 (desktop, standalone version). At least not unless there is some special addin that has to be activated.

I have seen all the answers and am using the working solution.

I don’t know why you keep commenting. I’ve told you which ones worked and which ones don’t. I really don’t think anymore feedback on this topic is necessary.

Oh i didnt see that comment. anyways thanks.

You could try using the following in Excel 2021


=LET(a, FORMULATEXT(B2),TRIM(LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(RIGHT(a,LEN(a)-1),"*",REPT(" ",100)),100)))


In MS365
=INDEX(TEXTSPLIT(FORMULATEXT(B2),{"=","*"},,1),1)


Or,
=TEXTAFTER(TEXTBEFORE(FORMULATEXT(B2),"*"),"=")


One more alternative :
=LET(
     a,FORMULATEXT(B2),
     REPLACE(SUBSTITUTE(a, RIGHT(a, LEN(a)-FIND("*",a)+1),),1,1,))



For older Windows versions of Excel, you can use:
=FILTERXML("<t><s>" & SUBSTITUTE(MID(FORMULATEXT(R35),2,255),"*","</s><s>") & "</s></t>","//s[1]")

